# Is it possible to use split view pane in Grid on asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How can I implement **splitview pane** in **Grid** with`<a>` tag? 
I use [this](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy) example in my code and want include [this pane](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/pane)
I want Grid / Hierarchy (second grid) `<a>` tag(like button) and change grid with another pane.
Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried ? Show us your attempts.

Comment: I'm new on asp.net . I don't know how I must realization it. I try `columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress).ClientTemplate("code of  second link in my question");`